# Failed to assign NA to any numerics

Tags: r

I have a data set looks like this:

```
     workshop   gender  q1  q2  q3  q4  
1   1   f   1   1   5   1
2   2   f   2   1   4   99
3   .   f   9   2   4   3
4   2   .   3   9   99  3
5   1   m   4   5   2   4
6   .   m   9   9   5   5
7   1   .   5   3   99  4
8   2   m   4   5   5   99
```

I don't know why I just cannot assign the "9" and "99" to "NA". I have searched on the Internet and tried to use "T=TRUE" or "rm(T)" as I probably mistakenly set the "T" to "NA" and masked that. But all failed.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
    mydataNA <- read.table("mydataNA.txt", 
na.strings = ".")

    mydataNA$q1[q1 == 9] <-NA
    mydataNA$q2[q2==9] <- NA
    mydataNA$q3[q3==99] <- NA
    mydataNA$q4[q4==99] <-NA
```

Comment: Try `mydataNA$q1[mydataNA$q1 == 9] <-NA`

Comment: I tried to fix your link, but couldn't.  The most effective way to show us your data, short of giving us all of it, is to cut and paste the **text** of `head(mydataNA)` or `str(mydataNA)` of `summary(mydataNA)`

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker, sorry I am beginner in programming. I thought copy paste the text would alter the format. I can edit that.

Comment: The simplest fix is to fix it when you import the data. You already have `na.strings = "."`, just add the others: `na.strings = c(".", "9", "99")`

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone!!!@Gregor